# Parser to json JSON array using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am doing an IOS (swift) app that communicates with a server.
Response from server is a JSON array which contains some JSON objects. 
When i show by console string response is fine:

```
[{"NAME":"","SURNAME":"","ID":5,"USERNAME":"dpcabo2"},{"NAME":"","SURNAME":"","ID":10,"USERNAME":"default"},{"NAME":"","SURNAME":"","ID":11,"USERNAME":"esteban"}]
```

But when i try parser this info to json using this:

```
   var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.my_data!,
               options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

println("\(jsonResult)")
```

app crashes.

So i need a solution to parser correctly this information.

Ps.self.my_data! is a NSMutableData.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think `jsonResult` should be `NSDictionary`?  You even say yourself that the server returns a JSON **array**.

Comment: ummm, i don't know, when server returns only one user it sends a json object and this way runs ok, but when returns a json array i don't know how parser it, some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for parsing. It prints and parse you object properly.

```
import Foundation

let jsonObject: [AnyObject] = [
    ["NAME":"","SURNAME":"","ID":5,"USERNAME":"dpcabo2"],
    ["NAME":"","SURNAME":"","ID":10,"USERNAME":"default"],
    ["NAME":"","SURNAME":"","ID":11,"USERNAME":"esteban"]
]


let jsonOptional: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)
```

Response is as below:

```
[["USERNAME": "dpcabo2", "ID": 5, "NAME": "", "SURNAME": ""], 
["USERNAME": "default", "ID": 10, "NAME": "", "SURNAME": ""], 
["USERNAME": "esteban", "ID": 11, "NAME": "", "SURNAME": ""]]
```